# writing through pipes

Tags: c, arrays, struct, pipe

I am allocating memory for an array of pointers to a struct

```
FreqRecord* record = malloc(MAXRECORDS * sizeof (FreqRecord));
```

and reading from another process through a pipe that has already built this record

```
    int length = 0;
    if ((length = read(fdr[0][0], record, MAXRECORDS * sizeof (FreqRecord)))<0){
       perror("reading from pipe\n");
       exit(1);
    }
```

These pieces of code are in a loop and i expect different reults everytime. However it always end up being exactly identical to what the previous pipe wrote before

here is how struct is definer

```
typedef struct {
    int freq;
    char filename[PATHLENGTH];
} FreqRecord;
```

Comment: This isn't clear; are you saying that the data you read doesn't match what you wrote?  What's writing to the pipe?

Comment: Is the OP surprised that pipe writes are atomic? _man 7 pipe_ and [http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-Atomicity.html](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-Atomicity.html) might shed some light.